# Pay grading differential between Deputy and Director positions

Tags: communication, job-change

My organisation created a deputy director post and placed deputy on same pay scale as me the director. I initially accepted this but on consideration believe it is unfair. Can I challenge and ask for a pay differential to be established? Could I ask for this to be backdated to the time the new post started?

Comment: You can ask for anything you like. But what's your actual goal here? If you think you are deserving of a pay rise, make that case based on your performance not based on what someone else is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask.. but I think you're going to need a better reason than *"I don't like that someone with the word deputy in their title gets paid the same as me"*. Actually scratch that, you're going to need a *much* better reason than that.

If you want a raise then you're going to have to make your case for why *you* deserve a raise in the normal manner - make a case to the business why you're getting paid *X* but are worth *Y*: added value, more experienced than you were, achieved this and that, etc. But whatever reasoning you use it should have nothing to do with the new deputy role.

> could i ask for this to be backdated to the time the new post started?

Not a chance!

Answer (score 0):

You can ask but you will need a good case and a goal that makes sense for the company not for you.  Asking to create (yet) another pay scale is creating work for HR and needs a purpose.

Do you expect all deputy directors to make less than all directors?  This doesn't seem reasonable to me.  For example, at a software company, I would not be surprised at all to see the Director of Engineering make much more than the Director of HR and easily see a Deputy Director of Engineering to make more also.   How would you address something like this in your plan?

If you can't create a concrete plan to cover the whole issue for your company, it may just come across as a personal issue and get little traction.